# Is the Android API accessible from any script/program running on the linux layer ?

Tags: android, linux, api, sdk, sms

I'm looking to know if one can use the SMS/MMS api from the linux layer, ie: in a shell/perl/python script for ex.

More extensively, is it possible to use the full android API from such a script/program, with just an import/include of android lib ?

Thanks

Comment: Good question! I want to use Android as a Linux distro, too. Now I can cross-compile to Android (Linux-ARM), and my server apps are running like charm. But I want to use at least native Linux services of Android distro, like SQLite, OpenGL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:System-architecture.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but it must be work: if you don't avoid of writing an Android app (not like me), you should write a bridge app (in Java), which receives commands on a channel - it should be a simple web server. The bridge app (webserver) should implement a set of Android API, and provide it as a web service: http://myphone?phone-call=Mum or http://myphone?add-calendar-event=20120008_1200,lunch,30 - I know, there're lot of Android API calls, and this method does not fits for more complex app-OS functions (with callback etc.), but simple, one-way commands should work.

You can call this interface even from another host, say, from your desktop computer. Oh, wait, this is not a new idea, *there are already apps like this*, which are - I think - doing the same, they provide not just a plain service, but even nice Ajax app interface to your phone, here's one: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid

Also, the service should be protected, avoid sending lot of SMSes to your contacts with random HTTP requests.

CON: You should write an Android app, which provides each function you need. 
CON: Have to write Java code and use Android SDK. Not a fun.
CON: The bridge app should be running in the background, Linux program must be started somehow.

PRO: For a single service (e.g. sending SMS) it's a good choice.
PRO: This method will be compatible with future Android releases. (Hopefully.)
PRO: You can reach the service from other computers, you have not to use phone as user interface. (Hm, is a low-end Android phone cheaper than a SMS-bridge?)